# What are the best metrics to use for data drift detection of a Binary classification model on a tabular imbalanced numerical data

Tags: classification, dataset, metric, data-drift

I have a very unbalanced 2 data sets, the first is the one that the model was trained on (old training data), and the second is the newly collected data
I want to see if the model performance dropped due to a shift in the data patterns before considering retraining the model with new data.
Both Datasets have the exact same features and the same feature order (the only difference between both datasets is the number of data points, where the old training data has significantly more data, almost 10 times the new data sample).
The data is tabular, the model task is binary classification, also the ground truth column exists in both datasets and all features are numerical (int or float only).
what are the best drift detection metrics/approach to use for this case, please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.